# Stuck with a looping situation using jinja template with Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am stuck with a looping situation using jinja template with Ansible.

My jinja template:

```
{% for int in interfaces | difference(existing_conf) %}
interface {{ int }}
{% for ip in dhcp_servers | difference(existing_conf) %}
  ip dhcp relay address {{ ip }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

```
TASK [view the existing config] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1] => {
    "existing_conf": [
        "Vlan1",
        "10.1.1.2",
        "10.1.1.3",
        "10.1.1.4",
        "Ethernet1/49",
        "10.1.1.2",
        "Ethernet1/50",
        "10.1.1.2"
    ]
}
TASK [Needed config] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1]
TASK [View the needed config] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1] => {
    "needed_conf": [
        "Vlan1",
        "10.1.1.2",
        "10.1.1.3",
        "10.1.1.4",
        "Ethernet1/49",
        "10.1.1.2",
        "10.1.1.3",
        "10.1.1.4",
        "Ethernet1/50",
        "10.1.1.2",
        "10.1.1.3",
        "10.1.1.4"
    ]
}
```

My variables:

```
interfaces=["Vlan1", "Ethernet1/49", "Ethernet1/50"]
dhcp_servers=["10.1.1.2", "10.1.1.3", "10.1.1.4"]
```

With my template, I am getting an empty config.

Config I want:

```
interface Ethernet1/49
  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.3
  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.4
interface Ethernet1/50
  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.3
  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.4
```

Note: I only want to add the config which is not in the running-config of switch.

Comment: Fix the error: `"template error while templating string: expected token 'name', got '|'"`

Answer (score 0):

Q: **"*... I am getting an empty config.*"**

A: There are no items to iterate over. The *difference*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ interfaces|difference(existing_conf) }}"
```

gives an empty list

```yaml
  msg: []
```

Comment: if I remove the difference, I get items but I am trying to add only the items which are not in running-config to a remote file. Even though idempotency will not copy the config which already exists but that's not what I am looking for. Is there a way to achieve that with template?